# DIV tamanho fixo com CSS (gerar PDF com MPDF)

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Preciso de uma DIV com tamanho fixo em centímetros `width:12.5cm;` e `height:7.5cm;`. Consigo manter esses tamanhos ao carregar a view, porém quando gero o PDF utilizando a classe mPDF do PHP, ele ignora o `height` e o aumenta de acordo com o conteúdo.
Preciso que independente do conteúdo, o tamanho seja mantido, mesmo que pra isso o conteúdo passe por cima das bordas.

CSS que estou usando na DIV:

```
.container-ficha {
        background-color:#ffffff;
        width:12.5cm;
        height:7.5cm;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }
```

L

Answer (score -1):

o CSS trabalha em forma de cascatas, ou seja, por hierarquias.

tente utilizar o código `!important` nas suas propriedades que não devem ser sobrescritas.

exemplo:

```
 .container-ficha {
            background-color:#ffffff;
            width:12.5cm !important;
            height:7.5cm !important;
            border:1px solid black;
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Tentei aqui, mas ainda assim ele ignora o height. Só acontece ao gerar o PDF, se deixar ele gerar a view comum, funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score -1):

A solução que encontrei foi adicionar `position:fixed;` a classe `.container-ficha`. Fazendo isso ele obedeceu ao `width` e `height`.